# AIM/MSN chat integration in Android

Tags: android, chat, asmack, aim

In the past few days, I tried GTalk/Facebook chat integration with [Android Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) and it's working fine.

I tried to implement the same logic for AIM/MSN chat integration with [Android Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) but it did not work.

Is there any special configuration needed for AIM chat integration? Please provide any way or any tutorial or reference link that can solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it uses XMPP server for chat?

Comment: I'm trying to get xmpp for facebook working now, I have gtalk but I'm having issues with the facebook authentication, would you mind sharing your working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MSN we can used [LiveSDK XMPP Sample for Android](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK/tree/master/Samples/XMPP-Samples/Android)

**Note:** There is some authentication issue in this library, I'm working on it and clear ASAP.

For AIM [this API](http://dev.aol.com) may help to get authentication.

Comment: i gone through those links what you shared, by using live sdk we cant chat with buddy i think it's a file sharing app. and from AIM api i did't get anything from that. can you share any links how you worked on this.please.